# R dense_rank without ordering

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, dense-rank

I am looking for something like dense_rank that would disregard the order of the ranked column.

```
# some data
df <- data.frame(
  cat = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A"),
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), length.out = 5, by = "days")
)
# showing the intended order
df$custom_order <- c(1,1,2,3,4)
```

The intended result is this. The second A is considered as part of the first A. The fifth A is a "new" A because the preceding cat is not an A.

```
  cat       date custom_order
1   A 2020-01-01            1
2   A 2020-01-02            1
3   B 2020-01-03            2
4   C 2020-01-04            3
5   A 2020-01-05            4
```

Does a function like this exist? I am aware it can be achieved with some lag() magic, but I was hoping there might be an easier way.

Comment: Do you need `df %>% mutate(custom_roder = rleid(cat))`

Comment: Wow, yes this is it!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to update the index whenever the current element is not matchingwith the previous one

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)  
df %>%
    mutate(custom_order = rleid(cat))
#    cat       date custom_order
#1   A 2020-01-01            1
#2   A 2020-01-02            1
#3   B 2020-01-03            2
#4   C 2020-01-04            3
#5   A 2020-01-05            4
```

---

In `base R`, this can be achieved with `rle`

```
df$custom_order <-  with(rle(as.character(df$cat)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

Comment: I tried rleid and it is awesome!!! It even handles multiple NA values the way I need (i.e. as "normal" values that are repeated).

Comment: data.table analogue: `DT[, g := .GRP, by=rleid(cat)]`

Comment: @Frank2 Thank you.  Would it be more faster with `DT[, g:= rleid(cat)]` to avoid the `by` operation